# How to pause counter for Table numbers

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I'm trying to create a list following tables: Table 1; Table 2A; Table 2B; Table 3.

Tables 2A and 2B are NOT subtables, but rather two very similar tables that my co-author wanted me to just rename it A & B instead of 2 separate table numbers. This numbering will most likely change as we add more new tables or remove some tables, so I instead of manually adding Table #s, but I'm trying to use Latex's counter, so the table # gets adjust as we modify these tables.

I tried the following Latex code:

```
\setcounter{table}{0} %Set this to 0 so it sets counter to start from 1.
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\caption{Linear Regression}
\input{"mod1estimate"}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}A}
\caption{Classification Tree (1) }
\input{"mod2pctestimate"}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}B}
\caption{Classification Tree (2)}
\input{"mod2lvestimate"}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\caption{Our New Preferred Model}
\input{"mod3estimate"}
\end{table}
```

However, the output Tables are: Table 1, Table 2A, Table 3B, Table 4. Is there any way I can pause the counter at Table 2A, so that my third table will become 2B? Or are there more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `\addtocounter{table}{-1}`

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}B}
```

to get 2B rather than 3B

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `\ContinuedFloat` from the `caption` package

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{A table}
    ...
\end{table}
...
\begin{table}
    \ContinuedFloat  % goes before `\caption`
    \caption{A table (cont.)}
    ...
\end{table}
```

This prevents the incrementation of the counter, which has the same effect of `\addtocounter{table}{-1}`.

[image]

In order to get labels like 2A and 2B, you need two more commands `\theContinuedFloat` and `\ContinuedFloat*`

```
\renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\Alph{ContinuedFloat}}

\begin{table}\ContinuedFloat*
    \caption{First table}
    ...
\end{table}
\begin{table}\ContinuedFloat
    \caption{Second table}
    ...
\end{table}
```

[image]

See [Section 3.3 Continued floats](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (version 2020/09/21) for more information